# Is IPv6 dead by now?

Tags: networking, internet, ipv6

Ten years ago there was a lot of talk about IPv6.

But just now I tried to disable IPv4 and to browse internet via IPv6.

It turned out, I basically can access only Google and Wikipedia with IPv4 disabled. Not Quora or StackExchange. Even not the IPv6 readiness testing sites like test-ipv6.com, which is not even resolved via IPv6 DNS (both of local provider or Google).

Some test sites that report 100% IPv6 readiness when both IPv4 and IPv6 are enabled, are not resolvable when IPv4 is off, like http://test-ipv6.ke.liquidtelecom.net/.

While the main google search site is working, the Google's own IPv6 testing site is not accessible or pingable via IPv6 only, and not resolvable via IPv6 DNS: https://ipv6test.google.com/

Yandex is also not accessible, while it can be resolved, it cannot be pinged.

Even from the [list](https://ungleich.ch/en-us/cms/blog/2019/02/05/list-of-ipv6-only-services/) of **IPv6-only** sites I was able to access only one, Google with IPv4 off.

So, my question is: should IPv6 be considered dead by now?

Comment: right now your question is asking for primarilly opinon-based responses so it will likely be closed. Instead reframe your question to focus on the current state of IPv6 adoption, and what progress the industry is making toward adoption, rather than asking for conclusions about the health of the proposition.

Comment: Voting to close. This question is really open-ended here and nobody can just say, “Yeah, on this date IPv6 will work for all…” and such. IPv6 adoption is not as pervasive as anticipated at this point. But the core issue of IPv4 addresses running out is very real. Perhaps you can get away with disabling IPv6 for now, but as time goes on the chances of things breaking on your side with a purely IPv4 machine networking is quite high. Unless you have a specific reason to disable IPv6, just keep it on.

Answer (score 2):

IPv6 is being used more than you know. Many wireless carriers (cell data) only assign an IPv6 address to your smartphone. The only reason you can get to IPv4-only sites from your smartphone is because your carrier also deploys a NAT64 gateway.

Also, it was **never the plan** to have a hard cutover from IPv4 to IPv6. It **has always been the plan** to add IPv6 to IPv4 and have both run side by side indefinitely, until some future era when IPv4 "dies on the vine"; eventually, nothing will be using IPv4 any more, and people will finally stop bothering to keep IPv4 working.

Comment: “Also, it was never the plan to have a hard cutover from IPv4 to IPv6.” This is the answer.

Comment: Its also worth pointing out that getting a 'publicly routable' IP address is more and more difficult and many ISPs use carrier grade NAT for IPv4. Its IPv4 that's dying by degrees.